# Как узнать username пользователя моего бота?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

вопрос максимально короткий. У меня есть бот,мне нужен пример кода,который заносит в базу данных username пользователей. Уже реализован код для сбора id пользователя,но мне нужен еще username

Comment: Что документация говорит по этому поводу?

Comment: Если вы приведете здесь уже имеющийся код, будет легче помочь вам.

Comment: Дело в том,что мне как раз таки и нужен код,который будет добавлять username пользователя в базу данных

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def member(message):
    print(message.chat.username)
    create_user_db(message.chat.username)


def create_user_db(username):
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.executemany('INSERT INTO users VALUES (?)', username)
    conn.commit()
```